# Viewing two pages Apple Pages 5.2.2

Tags: pages

In Apple Pages 5.2.2, how can I choose view 2-up? It used to be selectable in lower left corner of document...not any more. Thanks for any tips.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to get a two page view of your document in Pages 5.2.2. Open your document and select print from the file menu. At the bottom left of the box, where you see PDF, scroll to choose Open in Preview. Then under view in the menu bar, you can choose Two Pages, and you get a two pages view which can be scrolled vertically, but cannot be edited. You can cancel out of preview without printing. I couldn't get the two page option in regular preview, only in print preview.

Answer (score 0):

Two pages view isn't supported by the new Pages 5.2.2.
I found out when I opened with the new Pages, a document saved in a two pages view format. A warning message let me know that it wasn't supported. :(

I still use both Old and New versions of pages mainly for that feature! :)

I hope it helps.
ps: If you upgraded to the new pages ( not bought the mac with it) your old Pages version is still in your mac : Applications> iWork'09

Answer (score 0):

Stop the presses! The Apple Pages 7 update 5576, March 27 2018, MacOS 10.12 required, has the feature back! You can do into 2 page view again after several years! Maybe I can retire Pages 2009...
https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/pages/id409201541?mt=12

Answer (score -1):

Now when I make a document in pages I save a copy as a PDF. When I open the PDF document I go to View>2 page viewing. This is fine if you're just reading but useless for editing. Terrible "upgrade" to the program. Good luck.

Comment: Exactly the same answer as already provided in Feb. 2015.